# How can I show that these assets do not satisfy a 1-factor model?

Tags: factor-models

Suppose these two assets satisfy a 1-factor model:
$$
R_1= E(R_1) + F + ε_1
\\
R_2= E(R_2) - F + ε_2
\\
$$
where: $$
E(F)=E(ε_1)=E(ε_2)=0
\\
Var(F)=1, Cov(F,ε_1)=Cov(F,ε_2)=Cov(ε_1,ε_2)=0
\\
Var(ε_1)=Var(ε_2)=\sigma^2
\\
$$
If:
$$
S_1=R_1
\\
S_2= \psi R_1 + (1-\psi)R_2
\\
\psi= 1/(2+\sigma^2)
$$
How can I show that $S_1$ and $S_2$ do not satisfy a 1-factor model with factor F?  [DONE]

Also i wanted to ask if $S_1$ and $S_2$ satisfy the following zero-factor model:
$$
S_1= E(S_1) + \widetilde{\epsilon_1}
\\
S_2= E(S_2) + \widetilde{\epsilon_2}
$$
where the variances of the epsilons and their covariance is zero.

Comment: Perhaps try to look for violations of zero covariances?

Comment: thanks, I think that it is the way to solve the first part, indeed I obtained a covariance different from zero. 
However, I am not sure about the definition of Zero-factor model used in the last part of my question, so I do not know how to proceed

Comment: If you already have an answer to the first question, why do you keep it in your post and make users work on it? :)

Comment: I'm sorry I had already computed the covariance but I was not sure it was the way to show what the exercise was asking, you just helped me realizing that

Comment: If you have an answer you are unsure about, you can always include it in your post and let us verify it.

Comment: okay, thank you